# How to change MvxDialogFragment layout

Tags: xamarin, xamarin.android, mvvmcross, android-alertdialog

I want to change the default AlertDialog layout size.

I created class:

```
public class SampleDialog : MvxDialogFragment
{
    public override Dialog OnCreateDialog(Bundle savedInstanceState)
    {
        var dialog = new AlertDialog.Builder(Context);
        dialog.SetView(View.Inflate(Context,Resource.Layout.SampleDialog,null));

        return dialog.Create();
    }

    public override void OnStart()
    {
        if (Dialog == null) { return; }

        Dialog.Window.SetLayout(200,460);
        base.OnStart();
    }
}
```

and it's layout:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">
    <TextView
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="@string/text1" />
    <TextView
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="@string/text2" />
</LinearLayout>
```

And i'm creating dialog from fragment view:

```
var dialog = new SampleDialog
{
    ViewModel = ViewModel,
    Cancelable = true
};

dialog.Show(FragmentManager, "");
```

Tryed to set layout width in OnCreateDialog method,OnStart, or directly by setting LinearLayout.layout_width property, but the result is the same.

How this can be configured?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**Inflating the layout**

When inflating the layout you can make use of either the default inflator or Mvvmcross `BindingInflate` which will apply any xml bindings you require.

*Default inflator:*

```
public override Dialog OnCreateDialog(Bundle savedInstanceState)
{
    base.EnsureBindingContextSet(savedInstanceState);

    var dialog = new AlertDialog.Builder(Context);
    dialog.SetView(Activity.LayoutInflater.Inflate(Resource.Layout.SampleDialog, null));

    return dialog.Create();
}
```

*Mvvmcross xml binding inflator:*

```
public override Dialog OnCreateDialog(Bundle savedInstanceState)
{
    base.EnsureBindingContextSet(savedInstanceState);

    var dialog = new AlertDialog.Builder(Context);
    dialog.SetView(this.BindingInflate(Resource.Layout.SampleDialog, null));

    return dialog.Create();
}
```

**Sizing the layout**

The `Dialog.Window.SetLayout()` takes in the pixel values for 200(width) and 460(height) which will vary in physical size with different device screen resolutions.

A better approach would be to use dp and convert it to pixels:

Add the desired size dimensions to your `dimens.xml`

```
<resources>
    <dimen name="dialog_width">400dp</dimen>
    <dimen name="dialog_height">200dp</dimen>
</resources>
```

Update your `SampleDialog`

```
public override void OnStart()
{
    base.OnStart();

    var width = Resources.GetDimension(Resource.Dimension.dialog_width);
    var height = Resources.GetDimension(Resource.Dimension.dialog_height);

    Dialog.Window.SetLayout((int)width, (int)height);
}
```